# datatables in R "," and keyby, and "." confusion

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, kable

I'm rewriting someone else's  `R` code into `python`, and I don't know `R`.

So I'm trying to decipher what things mean.

What does this line mean?

```
kable(DT[, .N, keyby=.(target=get(y))], format="html")
```

So DT is the datatable itself, and y is a column within DT. But I think it's trying to create a table wherever y exists?

There's also this follow up line:

```
id_bady1= DT[! get(y) %in% c(0,1), get(id)]
```

Documentation for `R` says that get returns the object the matches the input, but how does that work when there are multiple matches?

Comment: Please give an example for *when there are multiple matches*

Comment: @jogo `y <- "cyl"; cyl <- "yeehaw"; data.table(mtcars)[, get(y)]` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The content of `y` is the name of a column of the datatable, see:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- mtcars
setDT(DT)
y <- "cyl"
DT[, .N, keyby=.(target=get(y))]
```

IMHO it is here *complete matching* (not *partial matching*):

```
DT[, cylA:=7] # construct a second column that begins with "cyl"
DT[, .N, keyby=.(target=get(y))]

y <- "cy"  ## no complete matching possible
DT[, .N, keyby=.(target=get(y))]
### Error in get(y) : object 'cy' not found
```